# Title of old sci fi movie with two men compelled by a telepathic force to build a device

Tags: story-identification, movie, telepathy

This was a movie in color 50s 60s maybe 70s.  It opened with two men, maybe scientists, who were in an office or at a home, and who were compelled by a telepathic force to build a device - they had no idea what they were building.  It turned out to be some sort of screen on the wall - I seem to remember the keystone shape of the Heinz 57 shield - and it either functioned as a communication device, a teleportation device, or both.  The two find themselves on another planet and during one scene they see a demonstration of a laser generator that burns a hole through a very thick steel plate.  I don't remember much else, including what the aliens wanted...

Comment: This Island Earth (1955) was my first thought, too.

Comment: You are all amazing.  This is the movie - sorry the question was a duplicate - my memory of the plot was not sufficient or accurate enough to realize that!